# Phantom JS synchronous AJAX request : NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, phantomjs

I am making a synchronous ajax call ( ajax settings async: false ). This works well.

Now I'm trying to write an automated test for this in phantomJS and I'm getting this error

```
NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101
```

I checked my service logs and it seems like service is not getting any request.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try disabling the web security by using the command-line option `--web-security=no` when running your script. (`phantomjs --web-security=no yourscript.js`)

From the PhantomJS reference (http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html):

"`--web-security=[true|false]` enables web security and forbids cross-domain XHR (default is true). Also accepted: `[yes|no]`

Comment: Correct work for me, that's not problem of `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: awesome.. thanks.. it was driving me crazy. I love phantom but they really need to work on their exception handling... give better explanations of what happened

Comment: I'm using phantomjs as a driver for xrayjs for web scraping and this causes it to just run forever and not output anything.