# Prerenderer IO: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://::1:12301/dnode/info And NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101:

Tags: javascript, node.js, seo, phantomjs

I have installed [Prerenderer IO](https://github.com/prerender/prerender) on my Mac Machine (OS X Yosemite 10.10.3). Right out of the installation, I ran `sudo npm install` and run `sudo node server.js` to get the following errors:

```
phantom stdout: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://::1:12302/dnode/info. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

phantom stdout: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://::1:12301/dnode/info. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

phantom stdout: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101: A network error occured in synchronous requests.

  .../node_modules/phantom/shim.js:1815
  .../node_modules/phantom/shim.js:1842

phantom stdout: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101: A network error occured in synchronous requests.

  .../node_modules/phantom/shim.js:1815
  .../node_modules/phantom/shim.js:1842

2015-08-04T13:45:47.307Z getting https://google.com
phantom stdout: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://::1:12303/dnode/info. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101: A network error occured in synchronous requests.

  .../node_modules/phantom/shim.js:1815
  .../node_modules/phantom/shim.js:1842

phantom stdout: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://::1:12304/dnode/info. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

phantom stdout: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101: A network error occured in synchronous requests.

  .../node_modules/phantom/shim.js:1815
  .../node_modules/phantom/shim.js:1842
```

I try entering a url `http://localhost:3000/https://google.com` and it hangs up after a few minutes.

I have changed the permissions and tried installing globally. Both does not work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and altered this file `lib/server.js` on line 70 like from this:

`var args = ["--load-images=false", "--ignore-ssl-errors=true", "--ssl-protocol=tlsv1"];`

to that:

`var args = ["--load-images=false", "--ignore-ssl-errors=true", "--ssl-protocol=tlsv1", "--web-security=no"];`

And now your NETWORK_ERROR should disappear.

See this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913170/phantom-js-synchronous-ajax-request-network-err-xmlhttprequest-exception-101) or tihs [github issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10985) for more informations.