# Send an Ajax request in CasperJS and loop through results

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am currently trying to fetch json values(mainly urls) from a GET call and assign this to a variable. I would ultimlately like to loop through the values and open each url with casper. However, I seen to have the incorrect concept on fetching values through an ajax call with casperjs. I read through the documentation but dont seem to understand why I am still getting error `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: __utils__`?

```
casper.start();
var url = "http://dev.web-ui.com/generate.php";

casper.then(function(url) {
    var results = __utils__.sendAJAX(url, "GET");
});

casper.run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two problem:

- The `url` parameter is not a URL, but the last loaded page resource object which contains the URL.
- `__utils__` is not available outside of the page context. You can require it if you want, but that probably won't fix your problem, because the dummy `document.location` outside of the page context has not the same domain as the URL you want to query, so that request may fail due to cross-domain restrictions. It's best to do this in the page context.

Example code:

```
casper.then(function(resource) {
    var results = this.evaluate(function(url){
         return __utils__.sendAJAX(url, "GET");
    }, resource.url);
    this.echo(results);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you inside a casper test ? If so, maybe `var __utils__ = require('clientutils').create();` would fix it. I can't try it myself right now unfortunately.

Comment: Oh I did miss that. Now added that part but now I am getting `NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101: A network error occured in synchronous requests.`

Comment: Just by googling a bit : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913170/phantom-js-synchronous-ajax-request-network-err-xmlhttprequest-exception-101

Comment: yes, i have it set to false for web security - `var casper = require('casper').create({ pageSettings: { webSecurityEnabled: false } });`

Comment: In the docs they say to pass it in the CLI call
`Don’t forget to pass the --web-security=no option in your CLI call in order to perform cross-domains requests when needed`
Since you seem to do a cross domain request that's probably the cause.