# Node 4.2.0 phantom stdout: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101: A network error occurred in synchronous requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cron, phantomjs

Calling the following code in node 4.2.0, it's executed in a node cron job and not via terminal. The site I'm 'requesting' is http://www.milb.com/index.jsp?sid=t402.

```
module.exports.dynamicRequest = function(url, callback) {
  var makeDynamicRequest = function(attempt) {
    if (attempt === 4) {
      svghost.delPhantom();
      return callback(new Error('Phantom had 3 failures'));
    }
    svghost.getPhantom(function(err, ph) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.stack);
        setTimeout(function() {
          ph.exit();
          svghost.delPhantom();
          attempt++;
          makeDynamicRequest(attempt);
        }, Math.pow(2, attempt) * 300);
      } else {
        ph.createPage(function(page) {
          page.open(url, function(status) {
            if (status === 'success') {
              page.get('content', function(content) {
                ph.exit();
                svghost.delPhantom();
                callback(null, content);
              });
            } else {
              ph.exit();
              svghost.delPhantom();
              setTimeout(function() {
                attempt++;
                makeDynamicRequest(attempt);
              }, Math.pow(2, attempt) * 300);
            }
          });
        });
      }
    });
  };
  makeDynamicRequest(1);
};
```

svghost is just a simple phantom wrapper that recursively attempts to create a phantom object until successful. I'm confident svghost is not the issue. This works locally 100% of the time but I'm seeing this error when the cron job runs on our server: `phantom stdout: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101: A network error occurred in synchronous requests.`

Here's the stack trace:

```
phantom stdout: /srv/apps/scraper/node_modules/spoton/node_modules/phantom/shim.js:7608 in send
/srv/apps/scraper/node_modules/spoton/node_modules/phantom/shim.js:7608 in _start
/srv/apps/scraper/node_modules/spoton/node_modules/phantom/shim.js:7635
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node/issues/345), it seems related and / or helpul.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your phantom instance using `phantom.create` you should add a `--web-security=no` argument or use the `options` object an add `'web-security':'no'`to it.

It would result in something like this:

`phantom.create({'web-security':'no'}, callback...)`

And no your NETWORK_ERROR should disappear

See this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913170/phantom-js-synchronous-ajax-request-network-err-xmlhttprequest-exception-101) or tihs [github issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10985) for more informations.

Comment: Passing an object does not work, but a string does: `phantom.create('--web-security=no', function(ph) {...` (phantomjs 2.1.1).

Comment: @medik maybe not the same version anymore?